# Flextable seems to be incompatible with multicol LaTex package

Tags: flextable

When running the following rmardown code

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
secondc <- c("X.*","X",NA,"X",NA,NA)
thrirdc <- c("Y","Y",NA,"X",'Y',NA)

tabela <- data.frame(firstc,secondc, thrirdc)
ft <- flextable(tabela)
ft <- access(ft)
ft <- hline_top(ft)

ft <- fit_to_width(ft, max_width = 2.2)
ft <- align(ft, i = 4, j=2:ncol(tabela), align = "center")
ft <- set_table_properties(ft, layout = "autofit", width = 1)
```

\begin{enumerate}
\item My first line.
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item `r ft`
\item `r ft`
\item `r ft`
\item `r ft`
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
````

I get the following error:

output file: flextable.knit.md

! Package longtable Error: longtable not in 1-column mode.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile flextable.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See flextable.log for more info.
Execution halted

Comment: A workaround is to produce a pdf from the table and use the pdf inside the `multicol` enviroment.

Answer (score 2):

`Flextable` appears to have several weaknesses when the output is a PDF document. My question, which I am now answering, is an example of one of those weaknesses.

One idea to get around these congenital `Flextable` weaknesses is to always use HTML as output and then use `Pagedown` package to convert the table to PDF, subsequently inserting the table into the document as an image.

Since the PDF produced by `Pagedown` package is vector-based, then no graphical quality is lost.

Below is an example of how to get a table created by `Flextable` into a high quality PDF. The last 3 lines of code could be encapsulated in a function of `Flextable` package (similarly to `quick_pdf` function of `Huxtable` package).

It's a shame that `Flextable` works so limitedly with PDF and at the same time has a superb syntax!

```
library(flextable)
library(pagedown)

m <- rbind(
  c("A","B","C"),
  c("D","E","F")
)

dados <- as.data.frame(m)

ft <- flextable(dados)
ft <- theme_box(ft)

save_as_html(ft,path = "/tmp/lixo.html")
chrome_print("/tmp/lixo.html","/tmp/lixo.pdf")

system("cd /tmp; pdfcrop lixo.pdf")
```