# Unable to include multiple flextable in RMarkdown PDF minipage

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, flextable

I am trying to use the R `{flextable}` package to create a PDF. It doesn't like `{multicol}` ([SO: Flextable seems to be incompatible with multicol LaTex package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68104689/flextable-seems-to-be-incompatible-with-multicol-latex-package)) due to longtables not being allowed in multicol. So I have instead used `{minipage}`.

When trying with a single `flextable` the document succesfully knits:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "30/08/2021"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: lualatex
geometry: margin=1.5cm
---

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
```{r iris}
flextable::flextable(iris[1:5, ])
```
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
Content on the right hand side
\end{minipage}
````

However, when adding in a second table, it doesn't convert correctly to the .tex file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "30/08/2021"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: lualatex
geometry: margin=1.5cm
---

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
```{r iris}
flextable::flextable(iris[1:5, ])
```
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
```{r iris2}
flextable::flextable(iris[1:5, ])
```
\end{minipage}
````

The .tex content looks fine for the first minipage, but appears as this in the second minipage:

```
\textbackslash begin\{minipage\}{[}t{]}\{0.5\linewidth\}
```

Is there something I need to add to the Rmd file to prevent this from happening? I have tried using `print` and `cat` and causes the same output/error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that  Pandoc does not understand that the second `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}` is supposed to be verbatim LaTeX as well.
As a workaround, you can mark this line as [raw LaTeX](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/raw-latex.html):

````
```{=latex}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
```
````

The same applies to the closing `\end{minipage}`.

However, this generates a paragraph break between the two minipages such that they are not side-by-side anymore. The only remedy I found thus far is to use the raw LaTeX syntax for the first minipage, too:

````
---
title: "2 Flextables"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: lualatex
    keep_tex: yes
geometry: margin=1.5cm
---

```{=latex}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
```
```{r iris}
flextable::flextable(iris[1:5, 2:4])
```
```{=latex}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
```
```{r iris2}
flextable::flextable(iris[1:5, 2:4])
```
```{=latex}
\end{minipage}
```
````

**Output:**
[image: Output]

Comment: Wasn't aware of `{=latex}`, tried with my project and works there too. Thanks!